# client side encryption in jQuery & decryption in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, encryption, crystal-reports, client-server

I am trying to create a function where I encrypt the string from the client-side and decryption in the PHP side. mainly use in while login.
I show the CryptoJs lib but there is tough to understand who to decode in PHP also there are lots of threads about this same but there is no decryption in PHP.
I made a code but this is not working, Please help me with how do I make client-side encryption and server-side PHP decryption.

```js
var message = "MyText";
var key = "01234567890123456789012345678901";

var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(message, key);
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key);

$('#1').text("Encrypted: " + encrypted);
$('#2').text("Decrypted: " + decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
<div id="1"></div>
<div id="2"></div>
```

**PHP**

```
function myCrypt($value, $key, $iv)
{
    $encrypted_data = openssl_encrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return base64_encode($encrypted_data);
}

function myDecrypt($value, $key, $iv)
{
    $value = base64_decode($value);
    $data = openssl_decrypt($value, 'aes-256-cbc', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
    return $data;
}

$valTxt = "MyText";
$key = "01234567890123456789012345678901"; // 32 bytes
$vector = "1234567890123412"; // 16 bytes
$encrypted = myCrypt($valTxt, $key, $vector);
$decrypted = myDecrypt($encrypted, $key, $vector);
print $encrypted . "\n";
print $decrypted . "\n";
```

Comment: if you put the key in the js anyone can decode it, whats the point of encryption if people can decrypt it?

Comment: I don't know how to make the function for decrytion?